# Image with border and figcaption

Tags: html, css

Been trying to solve this for some time but keep getting stuck. Some help would be much appreciated.

For an assignment I needed to create a **`content-box`** ***with image inside it*** which **`has a border and also figcaption`** and is **horizontal centered** within the **box**. There has to be some **padding between** the **image** and the **border**.

I've managed to create it but the feedback I got was "**Why** does img have a **max-width of 100%**"? If I leave that out the image ***doesn't stay*** within the border of the figure. I tried applying CSS on the `<img>` element as well but that ***doesn't seem to work*** as the figcaption doesn't go along.

The **result** I am getting is how it should look like but the code isn't (completely) accurate. I've put the code I have in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ron1986/wufqcrs9/)

**HTML:**

```
    <h1>Games</h1>
     <section class="boardgames">
       <h2>Boardgames</h2>
       <figure>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573912303133-d1f823500a79?ixlib=rb- 
          1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80" alt="Chessboard with some pieces">
         <figcaption>Chessboard with some pieces</figcaption>
       </figure>
     </section>
     <section class="chessboard"></section>
```

**CSS:**

```
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .boardgames {
        box-sizing: content-box;
        display: flow-root;
        border: 0.25rem solid silver;
    }
    
    figure {
      border: 0.25rem solid silver;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-inline-start: auto;
      margin-inline-end: auto;
      margin-block-end: 20px;
      padding-inline-start: 2px;
      padding-inline-end: 2px;
      padding-block-start: 2px;
      padding-block-end: 2px;
    }
    
    figure img {
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    .chessboard {
        box-sizing: content-box;
        border: 5px solid silver;
    }
```

Anyone have any idea how to ***leave out the max-width*** of the ***image*** and still get the result I need? Hopefully my description is accurate enough. 
Thank you for advance.

Comment: Not really. You would need width: 100%. Just tell them "Cuz it needs to have `width: 100%`" :)

Comment: Are they asking to specify dimensions within HTML `img` tag? You can get around it by using something like `-moz-available` on FireFox, not sure the webkit though.

Comment: there is nothing wrong using max-width:100% or width:100% and it's what should be done here. Also your code can be simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/wfdhtoyc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right than there is no way how to have this code without **`width: 100%`**.
Not sure if it's gonna help but instead of having **`width: 100%`** in you css you can insert this **value** into **HTML** like this: `<img width="100%" />`.

I don't think there is way how to make it look the same way without specifying `width`.
You can check out this page from **[W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html)** there is a few examples of this:

Comment: it's not valid to use percentage inside width attrbute even if it works in some browsers